# move files from aws s3 loaction to another aws s3 location using NiFi execute script processor

Tags: python, amazon-s3, groovy, apache-nifi

I'm getting files into a S3 location on a weekly basis and I need to move these files after processing to another S3 location to archive the files. I have cloudera NiFi hosted on AWS. I can't use putS3Object+DeleteS3Object processors at the end of the flow because in this NiFi process because I'm decompressing the file and adding additional column (compressing file and dropping column hits performance). I need a python/groovy script to move files from S3 loaction. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: is NiFi a good fit for this ? - you want python script to do it - so just spin a lambda or a glue job, i am big Nifi fan but not everything is nail when you have NiFI :)

Comment: I had the process already running. I just need a script to run in ExecuteScript processor.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a python/groovy script to move files from S3 loaction. is there any other way to do this?

No, you don't. You can use the record processors or a script to update the files and push them to S3. We pull, mutate and reupload data like this all the time without having to control the upload with a script.

Comment: can you explain, how you are handling similar scenario without using any script. If possible can you upload the screenshot of the flow. Thanks.

Comment: You just pull the file down with FetchS3Object, use CompressContent (unzip mode) or UnpackContent to decompress, update with any tool you want, and then use CompressContent -> UpdateAttribute (to change the file location in S3) and then PutS3Object.

Comment: For CSV, JSON, Avro, etc. you just need to use the record API processors and add the new column to your schema and you can use UpdateRecord to stitch in a new column without any code. If you have a complex update need, you use can use ScriptedTransformRecord.

Comment: The requirement is complex here. First I receive files into a s3 bucket(let's say source). I will process these files(decompress files + adding column) and move these files into another S3(destination) . After putting files to destination I need to move the files in source to a sub-prefix(archive). the sub prefix is a folder inside source bucket itself.

Comment: Well, one way you could do that is to set up the AWS CLI tools on the NiFi server and have ExecuteStreamCommand run the commands to move the source data within the source bucket after PutS3Object successfully runs.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to implement. All my trials are unsuccessful. can you mention what are the processor configurations that I need to set.

Comment: I have never used the AWS CLI. I just know that it's an option.